# Angular orderby with custom function + array for multiple values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I am using angular orderby with the custom function.  It looks like this:

Objects:

```
$scope.array = [{'field1': some_value,
                'field2': some_value,
                    ...
                'field10': some_value},
                    ...
                {'field1': some_value,
                    ...
                'field10': some_value} // Field can be more in the future
               ]
```

Controller:

```
$scope.array = $filter('orderBy')($scope.array, [function(item) {
    return customOrderFunction(item);
}, 'field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5',...,'field10']);
```

But it's not pretty && the field can be more in the future.  I try to make a string to reduce the code size.

```
var fieldString = ['field1', 'field2', ... 'field10'];

$scope.array = $filter('orderBy')($scope.array, [function(item) {
    return customOrderFunction(item);
}, fieldString.join()]);
```

But it gives an error.  Is there any possible way to achieve this with *orderBy*?  Or is there possible way to do this with *JavaScript*?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using plain old JS array [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom sort function instead? `orderBy` doesn't appear to have any special behaviour that you can't do with `sort`.

Comment: I see.  Then I am going to use sort()... :(